# How to delete Model Condition?

Tags: atk4

I wrote a function which is supposed to return an array of clubs for userId. I don't know why by when I add `where(Model_ClubUsers::$USERS_ID,$userId)` to `dsql()` it doesn't set the condition and I have to use `addCondition()`, but I need it only in this function. Is there a way to delete the condition before function returns?

```
function getUserClubs($userId){
    $columns = array('id',self::$NAME,self::$LOGO_NAME,self::$DESC);
    $this->addRelatedEntity('club_users', 'club_users', Model_ClubUsers::$CLUBS_ID, 'inner', 'related');
    $this->addField(Model_ClubUsers::$USERS_ID)->relEntity('club_users');
    $aAliasedColumns = $this->getAliasedColumns($columns, $this->entity_code);
    $this->addCondition(Model_ClubUsers::$USERS_ID,$userId);
    $rows = $this->dsql()->field($aAliasedColumns)->do_getAll();
    $aResult = array() ;
    foreach($rows as $key => $value){
        foreach($value as $vKey => $vVal){
            if($columns[$vKey]=='id'){
                $aRow['key'] = $vVal;
            }else if($columns[$vKey]==self::$LOGO_NAME){
                $aRow[$columns[$vKey]] = self::$CLUBS_LOGO_PATH.$vVal;
            }
            else {
                $aRow[$columns[$vKey]] = $vVal;
            }
        }
        $aResult[] = $aRow;
    }
    return $aResult;
}
```

Comment: addCondition() placed in init() function of a model, will always be executed and can be considered a global condition. If you add condition manually in a function, then it's not gonna be global. Calling dsql() returns dsql() object which has nothing do do with model anymore. Subsequently calling where() should affect that object only.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to 4.2 where the problem is no longer present:

```
$x=clone $this;
$x->addCondition();
```

also your syntax can be probably improved with the new 4.2 features.